# How to move databases to another second data source catlaog in AWS athena?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I have a lot of databases in the default `AwsDataCatalog`, and would like to move them to different catalogs. Eg moving from

```
AwsDataCatalog
 / Database1ProjectA
 / Database2ProjectA
 / Database1ProjectB
```

towards

```
ProjectA
 / Database1ProjectA
 / Database2ProjectA
ProjectB
 / Database1ProjectB
```

How can you create a new catalog in the same account and move databases to it? I was looking at `aws glue` commands but I don't see a way to move databases from catalogs.